# Protected worksheet with Epplus - need to allow filtering and sorting. Sorting not permitted

Tags: c#, .net, excel, spreadsheet, epplus

The purpose of the following method is to style and protect a worksheet after data has been written to it with Epplus. The styling is correct, and the appropriate cells (in a particular row) are protected. It is designed to allow sorting and filtering despite the fact that the "header" row cells are protected.

In the generated spreadsheet, Excel allows filtering to be performed. However, sorting is met with an error message. How to solve this?

```
public void FormatSpreadsheet(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
{
    ExcelRange range;

    // styling header cells...

    range.AutoFilter = true;

    // protect headers and allow sorting and filtering, amongst other things
    worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowAutoFilter = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowDeleteColumns = false;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowDeleteRows = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowEditObject = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowEditScenarios = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowFormatCells = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowFormatColumns = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowFormatRows = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowInsertColumns = false;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowInsertHyperlinks = false;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowInsertRows = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowPivotTables = false;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowSelectLockedCells = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowSelectUnlockedCells = true;
    worksheet.Protection.AllowSort = true;

    // set a random password so it's impossible for anybody to edit the protected cells...

    // autofit columns
    range = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, worksheet.Dimension.End.Row, lastHeaderCol];
    range.AutoFitColumns();
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @AhmadBagadood "the cell or chart you are trying to change is on a protected sheet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to actually *activate* the AutoFilter rather than just *allowing* it. To filter using first row of your worksheet as the header, the `range` object you have above will work, you just need to set one more property:

```
range.AutoFilter = true;
```

Comment: I tried this above the block of code setting the all `ws.Protection` properties (updated code above), and it still won't allow sorting in the generated Excel. "the cell or chart you are trying to change is on a protected sheet."

Comment: Ah! I missed that in your question, I was talking about the AutoFilter itself, not sorting. You can't sort data on a locked sheet, regardless of the `AllowSort` setting, and regardless whether you use the normal Sort command or the one built into AutoFilter. Sorting a locked sheet will require a macro (VBA), and will also require you to protect the sheet with the UserInterFaceOnly:=true option. This can't be set in EPPlus, you have to set it from a macro running inside your workbook (each time the workbook is opened).

Comment: Yes, I suspected that, as it seems others have had this problem as well. Does EPPlus support creating macros in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yup! Just a string assignment to your `workbook.CodeModule.Code` or `worksheet.CodeModule.Code` for workbook or sheet-level macros (event handlers, etc.), or create new modules with `Workbook.VbaProject.Modules.AddModule` and then set the `Code` property of the object that returns. And be sure the extension is set to `.xlsm`.